# Successive addition or deletion of vertices (or edges) in graph

Tags: graphs-and-networks

I am trying to perform a kind of dynamic graph simulation where vertices and edges of graph are added and deleted according to the current state of the graph at each time step.
I know that there are built-in functions such as `EdgeDelete` or `VertexAdd` which seem to do this job.

However, if I understand correctly, what these functions do is constructing a new graph object instead of modifying the existing graph g so something like `g = VertexDelete[g,b]` involves O(N) time complexity instead of O(1) which is too expensive for such tasks.

Even though I understand that this kind of simulation is best done by other programming languages, I am wondering if there exists a kind of (design) pattern to do such things.

If the situation is too general, maybe one easy example might be constructing a certain graph `g` and randomly removing a vertex each time recording the size of the giant cluster size. Currently my solution would be `g = VertexDelete[g, randomVertex[g]]`, given the assumption that we have a function `randomVertex[g]`.

First of all, is my understanding about the graph functionality true? If yes, what is the best way to implement such dynamical graph simulation?

--EDIT--

Following the comment, I tried to perform a benchmark measuring the time spent from a sample code presented below run on my old slow machine.

```
n = 4 10^3;
g = RandomGraph[ {n, 2 n}];
Timing[( g = VertexDelete[ g, #]; ) & /@ RandomSample[ Range[n]]  ][[1]]
```

After getting time from various sizes I could get the following plot which indicates the time complexity is around `O(N^2)`. If I did not make a mistake, it shows `VertexDelete`  is a costly operation!!

[image: Time taken from the sample code in double logarithmic scales]

Comment: "so something like g = VertexDelete[g,b] involves O(N) time complexity" <- is this an assumption or something you've actually measured?  I wouldn't jump to conclusions based on the fact that the graph *appears* to be copied.

Comment: I should have mentioned that I tried doing such simulations with Mathematica.  It's really useful for prototyping but once I knew how to do it I always re-implemented it in a faster language (C++).

Comment: @Szabolcs It was just my assumption since `VertexDelete` returns another objects and together with `=` I expect the copy was unavoidable. Sorry for my unproven assertion. I will check that and modify above according to what I've observed. Regarding your last comment, I am trying to do some experiments with Mathematica and wondering how such simulations can be implemented in a kind of 'Mathematica' way.

Comment: I am noticing that VertexContract is also expensive. Making my own functions on the edge list seem to be faster than using the native functions. Do you still think it is slow ?